# HTML "placeholder" attribute successfully fills form input, but "value" attribute doesn't (using Angular 2+)

Tags: html, angular2-forms, placeholder

I have an Angular UI where clicking an edit button transforms the member name heading into a form where you can edit and update the name. I want the form to be pre-filled with the existing name.

However, the problem occurs with the `value="{{member.name}}"` line in the code snippet below. The form simply appears blank. Why?

Using `placeholder="{{member.name}}"`sets the value correctly, but placeholder isn't the behavior I want.

```
<h4 *ngIf="!editMode">{{member.name}}</h4>
<form *ngIf="editMode" #f="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onEdit(f)">
    <input type="text" value="{{member.name}}" ngModel name="name">
    <button type="submit">Update</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To set the value of an input field use `[ngModel]` directive and put the variable as parameter. Usually one wants a ["two way binding"](https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt1#two-way-binding), that's why the `[]` and `()` are mixed.

```
<form *ngIf="editMode" #f="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onEdit(f)">
    <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="member.name" name="name">
    <button type="submit">Update</button>
</form>
```

It's possible to only use `[]` to only "set" the value of the input. See the following SO-question for details: 
[Difference between [(ngModel)] and [ngModel] for binding state to property?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42504918/difference-between-ngmodel-and-ngmodel-for-binding-state-to-property/42505026)

Source: https://angular.io/api/forms/NgModel

Comment: Thanks! I knew about two-way binding but never used it for this specific purpose.

Answer (score 0):

I came up to this answer looking for set the placeholder with a variable but didn't work with the solution above.

I solved with property binding, using `[placeholder]="myVar"` with [this helpfull link](https://www.cloudhadoop.com/angular-placeholder-example/)

```
<form *ngIf="editMode" #f="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onEdit(f)">
  <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="member.name" name="name" [placeholder]="myVar">
  <button type="submit">Update</button>
</form>
```

And the Angular component to set placeholder text:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-input-placeholder',
  templateUrl: './input-placeholder.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./input-placeholder.component.scss']
})

export class PlaceholderComponent {
  myVar = 'Please enter your name here';
}
```