# Angular 7 - Selecting a value of one dropdown is updating the others

Tags: angular

I have an html in my angular 7 application where I am displaying the same dropdown for every row. Selecting one dropdown is changing the value for the other. How do I make the selection unique to that particular dropdown.

html

```
<div class="upload-table">
            <table id="table1" class="center" >

                <tbody class="upload-name-style">
                    <tr *ngFor="let item of files; let i=index">
                        <td> <input kendoTextBox [(ngModel)]="item.relativePath" style="width: 350px" /></td>
                        <td><kendo-dropdownlist style="width:350px" [(ngModel)]="selectedDocumentItem"  [data]="DocumentTypes"
                            [filterable]="false" textField="Name"  valueField="Id">
                        </kendo-dropdownlist></td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>


        </div>
```

Component Code

```
DocumentTypes: any = {};
    selectedDocumentItem: { 'Id': any; 'Name': any; };

public getDocumentTypes() {
        this.documentUploadService.getDocumentTypes()
            .subscribe(data => {
                this.DocumentTypes = data;
                this.DocumentTypesForDropDown = this.DocumentTypes.map(x => x.Name);
                this.getDocumentUploadDetails();
                this.setGridOptions();
                this.setColumns();
            },
                err => {
                    this.Error = 'An error has occurred. Please contact BSG';
                },
                () => {
                });

    }
```

Comment: If they're all sharing the same model then of course they all select the same data. You could have a bunch of values for different 'selectedDocumentItem', one for each item in your list, but much better make your list a Component that is repeated as many times as you want. The component will wrap its own data nicely.

Comment: The same way you're doing for the input box: its model is `item.relativePath`, so each item has its own relativePath. Since you also want each item to have its own selected document, the dropdown's model should be `item.selectedDocumentItem`, not `selectedDocumentItem`.

Comment: I tried item.selectedDocumentItem and it seems to work

Answer (score -1):

you need to change this bit in your code:
[(ngModel)]="selectedDocumentItem"
if this one is the same they will change all together.
use the ngFor loops i intead.

Comment: Gary not sure what you mean

Answer (score -2):

**[(ngModel)]** is a two way binding and you are sharing same **selectedDocumentItem** with each Iterated item in files, so if One changes then other will also change.

Explained more here : [Difference between [(ngModel)] and [ngModel] for binding state to property?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42504918/difference-between-ngmodel-and-ngmodel-for-binding-state-to-property/42505026)

Here it is recommended to

1. Create a method in controller that will store the selected option.

   `selectedData(event: any) {
      this.storedData = event.target.value;
     }`
2. Then call it from html

   `(change)="selectedData($event)"`