# Added tag doe not added to ngx-chips model

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-ngmodel, ngx-chips

i am having a hard time understanding how new entry is added to the array of object specified in the directory.

I am using [ngx-chips](https://github.com/Gbuomprisco/ngx-chips)

Here is the sample [code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9-starter-material-8pkkex)  i made

here is the ngx-chip directive

```
<tag-input [ngModel]="items" (onAdd)="onFilterRuleAdded($event)"></tag-input>
```

Basically every time i add a new chip, it does not get added to my `items`
When i check the console logs, `items` contains the same entries. no new entries were added

How do i add every **new** entry in the `tag-input` to the define model `items`

Answer (score 0):

Fount it.

Turns on that i forgot to do two way binding.

Refer to this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42504918/difference-between-ngmodel-and-ngmodel-for-binding-state-to-property/42505026)

Basically i just enabled the **two-way binding**

Below is the working snippet

`<tag-input [(ngModel)]="items" (onAdd)="onFilterRuleAdded($event)"></tag-input>`

Do take on the **[(ngModel)]** syntax